# How were the blood globules of Lanciano weighed?

Tags: catholicism, communion, miracles

A long time ago, an RCC priest had addressed my doubts about the reality of presence of Christ in Host with the "numerous examples of Eucharistic miracles". The miracles had been:

> Five globules of dried blood found in the Host from time to time, which all five weight as much as any one of them

I have recently read a book about such miracles and it seems he has been referring to the miracle of Lanciano, where:

> Each individual globule weighed the same as the other individual ones (although different in size) or as all five together or as any other combination

The feature has been reported twice: just after the miracle and in 1574. No further reports of the feature are known despite further testing of the globules.

All sources I have read so far are vague about the method used for weighting the globules. The most they say is:

> The archbishop sent a scale for the weighing of the globules

As there is a comparison of one to all five I guess they were not weighted simultaneously on opposite arms of the scale. Rather there were weights used ([it seems spring scales were unknown at the time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighing_scale#History)).

This leads me to serious doubts about reliability of that feature - and thus of the whole miracle.

Are there any sources describing the weighting procedure?

Comment: There may be no source. I personally believe that one of the Last Day signs is science "so-called" having the ability to explain miracles. An unbeliever would point out that in the 700s it's unlikely the containers used to hold the separate globules would be so light as to precisely measure their weight, making the any-and-all-of-equal-weight conclusion easy.  A believer would say that faith precedes the miracle and applying oneself to prayer and the Holy Ghost resolves the matter.  If you're looking for incontrovertible scientific proof of this (or any) miracle, you'll likely be disappointed.

Comment: @JBH I think miracles by definition can not be explained. What I am trying to do is to decide, whether such event has ever happened or it is an urban legend. As for the Last Day, I guess you know Mt 24:23-24 - even a believer should be cautious. I have been literally told "Christ is there". Of course it may be just a sign to deceive. But if there were no sign, that would be even a greater deception.
I left RCC because I refused to force myself to believe in some fundamental dogmas. Now just trying to check, how honest may RCC be in things less fundamental.  Lk 16:10 works both ways I think.

Answer (score 2):

The most thorough study occurred in 1970-71. Pope Paul VI permitted a series of scientific studies on the precious relics to verify their nature. Dr. Odoardo Linoli, professor of anatomy and pathological histology, chemistry and clinical microscopy, and head physician of the hospital of Arezzo, conducted the study. He was assisted by Dr. Ruggero Bertelli, professor emeritus of human anatomy at the University of Siena. The analyses were performed in accord with scientific standards and documented, and Dr. Bertelli independently corroborated Dr. Linolis findings. In 1981, using more advanced medical technology, Dr. Linoli conducted a second histological study.

The Flesh, yellow-brown in color, has the structure of the myocardium (heart wall) and the endocardium, the membrane of fibrous-elastic tissue lining all the cardiac cavities. These have the same appearance as in the human heart. No traces of preservatives were found in the elements.

The blood was also of human origin with the type AB. Proteins in the clotted Blood were normally fractioned with the same percentage ratio as those found in the sero-proteic make-up of normal, fresh human blood. The blood contained these minerals: chlorides, phosphorus, magnesium, potassium, sodium, and calcium.

Comment: But the weighting miracle was not observed then, was it?